# HTML comments within comments?

Tags: html, multiline, comments

Is there a way to comment multiple lines... which already have some comments in them?

i.e.

```
<html>
<!-- Multi-line comment begin
  <head>
    <!-- This script does abcxyz -->
    <script>...</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello world!
  </body>
Multi-line comment end -->
</html>
```

It seems that even SO's syntax hilighting won't accept this...

Comment: It's a little annoying, but you can leave the other comments in by just removing the `-->` part of each one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are nested HTML comments possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442786/are-nested-html-comments-possible)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the key point is this:

> Note that comments are markup.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4

This is not valid markup:

```
<div <span/> />
```

... so neither is the one you mention.

---

Since all my sites are written in PHP I normally comment out code with PHP comments:

```
<?/*?>
<div>...</div>
<p>...</p>
<?*/?>
```

Perhaps you can use a similar trick.

Comment: sheesh, really? Am I the only one aggravated by this? o.O Thanks for the php advice though...

Answer (score 8):

No. Comments cannot be nested and HTML has only one style of comment.

Answer (score 5):

No. The closing comment tag --> will always end the comment section so if your comment includes a comment the closing tag of your included comment will end the comment section.

You can do a replace of --> in the section you are about to comment out to something unique so you can later just do another replace back to --> if you choose to undo your commenting.

Comment: Lolz. I guess doing this works...: `<--blahblah<--moreblahblah--<blahbleebloblah-->` (then when you uncomment you get: `blahblah<--moreblahblah--<blahbleebloblah`, which at least comments out a whole bunch so it's noticeable - then you just switch the < to >).

Answer (score 5):

If you're really stuck with some piece of HTML – pre-rendered at some uncontrollable source – which contains comments, and you need to make sure none of it is rendered on your page, you can always wrap it with a `script` tag like below, only thing is, you can't comment out `script` tags this way.

```html
 <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <!-- multiline "comment" below using script type="text/html" -->
     <script type="text/html">        
        Hello world!
        <!-- Look at me, I'm a comment :) -->
        <div>Yeah, whatever, I'm an element..</div>        
    </script>
    <span>Who cares, span is the man, the only visible one anyway!</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you need to comment out `script` tags, you could use a `textarea` as wrapper instead, off course doing it this way, you can't comment out `textarea` tags.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- multiline "comment" below using textarea style="display:none;" -->
    <textarea style="display:none;"> 
      <script>  
        alert("which won't show up..");  
      </script>
      Hello world!
      <!-- Look at me, I'm a comment :) -->
      <div>Yeah, whatever, I'm an element..</div>        
    </textarea>
    <span>Who cares, span is the man, the only visible one anyway!</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope, unfortunately HTML comments don't nest.

Answer (score 0):

it may still be useful for some developers, if use use vsCode as your IDE you can use an extension named Nest Comments in visual studio code market which work like a charm.

**this is the link**
[Nest Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=philsinatra.nested-comments)

Comment: This worked great for me.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

One can embed it in single or double quotes as a tag attribute. This requires then of course that the corresponding quotes are not occurring in between.

```html
<html>
<br comm='Multi-line comment begin
  <head>
    <!-- This script does abcxyz -->
    <script>...</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello world!
  </body>
Multi-line comment end'>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cehfumb2/2/