# How can I use HtmlTextWriter to write html comments?

Tags: c#, html, .net, htmltextwriter

I'm using [`HtmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt7b938d.aspx) to output html to a stream. However, I'm missing a way to write html comments. Of course, I could write an extension method doing

```cs
public static void WriteComment(this HtmlTextWriter writer, string comment)
{
  writer.Write("<!-- ");
  writer.WriteEncodedText(comment);
  writer.Write(" -->");
}
```

But that does feel a bit inelegant - is there some built-in method I'm not seeing?

Comment: Not quite the answer you're looking for, but a little more elegant: `writer.Write("<!-- " + comment + " -->");`

Comment: Its just another tag, no? We don't have a seperate method for each valid tag name in an\the HTML specification.

Comment: I like your extension.  It's spot on and elegant.

Comment: @Jodrell: comment is not a tag, that's the whole problem.

Comment: @Nolonar: good catch, but since comment's contents still have to be valid HTML (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4 ) I prefer the `WriteEncodedText` for them, safer solution.

Comment: I don't think that the specification says the comments have to be valid HTML. What if I wanted to write `<`, `>` or `&` into my comment? I don't doubt that, in practice, your method would work fine but, If I were extending the framework for everybody ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can argue, after checking the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#comments), that these extensions could be marginally more correct,

```
public static void WriteBeginComment(this HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagLeftChar);
    writer.Write("!--");
}

public static void WriteEndComment(this HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.Write("--");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
}

public static void WriteComment(this HtmlTextWriter writer, string comment)
{
    if (
        comment.StartsWith(">") || 
        comment.StartsWith("->") || 
        comment.Contains("--") ||
        comment.EndsWith("-"))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "text does not meet HTML5 specification",
            "comment");
    }

    writer.WriteBeginComment();
    writer.Write(comment);
    writer.WriteEndComment();
}
```

Comment: After reading [HTML comments within comments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3773719/3205) I was sure that `WriteEncodedText` is needed, but after testing this with w3c validator and in browser, seems that your safeguards are sufficient. Accepted.

Comment: @skolima, there appear to be limits on what char values can be considered "text" http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#text-syntax but, I think such validation goes beyond the scope of your extension.