# How to use wrap comment in HTML

Tags: html

Sample structure:

```
<div>1111111111</div> <!-- First line -->
<div>2222222222</div> <!-- Second line -->
<div>3333333333</div> <!-- Third line -->
```

It's OK. However, I want to wrap comment for this divs.

Sure, not working like this:

```
<!--
    <div>1111111111</div> <!-- First line -->
    <div>2222222222</div> <!-- Second line -->
    <div>3333333333</div> <!-- Third line -->
-->
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't have nested comments. You can remove the closing `-->` from one of the inner comments to make this work, though

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML comments within comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773719/html-comments-within-comments)

Comment: I know and thanks but it's not valid solution. I have very complex HTML file and not possible remove `-->` tags.

Comment: You might find it useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442786/are-nested-html-comments-possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really can't change any comments within the original source, but you can (or so it seems) wrap some lines in the source with something. You could turn the lines into a JavaScript multi line comment like I have done in this <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VH38/1/)**</kbd>.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
<div>1111111111</div> <!-- First line -->
<div>2222222222</div> <!-- Second line -->
<div>3333333333</div> <!-- Third line -->
    */
</script>
```