# Remove a part of string via first and last character?

Tags: java, android, string

I am getting a HTML string as a result of querying a remote XML feed. I use the result to set text to a `TextView`. The problem is that a string contains HTML comment tags which are not supported by the `TextView` element.

Now, I need a way to remove (substring) the resulting string by indicating the part which will be removed. I cannot work via start and end positions, but I have to use starting and ending string pattern (`<!--` as starting and `-->` as ending).

How can I do this?

Comment: post your code, it may help to fix your issue

Comment: @DaUltimateTrooper take care when using Regexes on HTML/XML though, only in some special cases they are the right tool (though this might be one). Often you should use a HTML/XML parser.

Comment: @Aerrow What code? It's a string I described :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular express, e.g.

```
    String input = "<!-- \nto be removed -->hello <!-- to be removed-->world";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<!--.*?-->", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int lastIndex = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        builder.append(input.substring(lastIndex, matcher.start()));
        lastIndex = matcher.end();
    }
    builder.append(input.substring(lastIndex));
    System.out.println(builder);
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps use this:

```
String str = "your html string";
int start = str.indexOf("<!--");
int end = str.indexOf("-->");
str = str.replace(str.substring(start, (end - start)), "");
```

Comment: Better use `int end = str.lastIndexOf("-->");`

Comment: nope, i dont think. Because you never know if there are a couple of comments inside html.

Comment: @Waqas I pointed it out because I thought there could be nested comments[, but I see it's not legal in valid HTMLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442786/are-nested-html-comments-possible). And I wasn't thinking in opening one comment, closing it and oppening (and closing) another comment.

Comment: @Waqas This code removed everything BUT the each ending "-->". If I try to add + 1 to end, then the app crashes.

Comment: Hm... have you tried this? Now it returns another string `ref; -->`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in here. I believe that since android is a tag here the answer will be relevant.

```
android.text.Html.fromHtml(instruction).toString()
```

[Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string).

Comment: +1 for posting just before me. You don't really need the `toString()` though.

Comment: I just copied the answer from the link below it ;). I suppose it serves for clarity just in case!

Comment: Thanks for a good tip. But I do not want to remove HTML. Just comments tag

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `HTML.fromHTML`

Comment: I cannot! That's the reason I posted this question

Comment: If so, use regex. Read Regular Expression Cookbook  http://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook-Jan-Goyvaerts/dp/0596520689/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336121466&sr=8-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Html.fromHtml()` method to use html-formatted text in a `TextView`, example:

```
CharSequence text = Html.fromHtml("before <!--comment--><b>after</b>");
myTextView.setText(text);
```

The TextView will now have the text "before **after**".