# Regex to extract between two strings (which are variables)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am looking to use regex to extract text which occurs between two strings. I know how to do if i want to extract between the same strings every time (and countless questions asking for this e.g. [Regex matching between two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736074/regex-matching-between-two-strings-in-python)), but I want to do it using variables which change, and may themselves include special characters within Regex. (i want any special characters, e.g. * treated as text).

For example if i had:

```
text = "<b*>Test</b>"
left_identifier = "<b*>"
right_identifier = "</b>
```

i would want to create regex code which would result in the following code being run:

```
re.findall('<b\*>(.*)<\/b>',text)
```

It is the `<b\*>(.*)<\/b>` part that I don't know how to dynamically create.

Comment: You may want to consider a non-greedy quantifier: `(.*?)` this matches as few characters as possible. so in the case of a string like "{left_identifier}stuff{right_identifier} {left identifier}more stuff{right_identifier}", you'll find only "stuff" and "more stuff" in two separate matches instead of "stuff{right_identifier} {left identifier}more stuff" in one match.

Comment: thanks - good spot - you are right - the non-greedy quantifier was what i mean!

Comment: Please note that using regex to parse HTML [is not recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/405017). You should use an HTML parser (whatever Python's equivalent of [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is) and then extract text from the appropriate tag.

Comment: @Phrogz - example was simplified - not parsing based on html tags in general, (although need to be able to cope with them, as they do crop into the text i am inputting). [for reference BeautifulSoup is the equivalent html parser in python].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) the identifiers:

```
>>> regex = re.compile('{}(.*){}'.format(re.escape('<b*>'), re.escape('</b>')))
>>> regex.findall('<b*>Text</b>')
['Text']
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
import re
pattern_string = re.escape(left_identifier) + "(.*?)" + re.escape(right_identifier)
pattern = re.compile(pattern_string)
```

The escape function will automatically escape special characters. For eg:

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.escape("<b*>")
\<b\*\>
```

Comment: Please also note the `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`, which is non-greedy capturing. Which is likely what you want here.

Comment: I tried performing the above with "PRIMARY KEY(\n" as the left identifier and ")" as the right identifier but didn't work for me. I wanted to get all the primary keys from the below:
  PRIMARY KEY
  (ROLE_ID)
  USING INDEX APP_ROLES.SR_PK
  ENABLE VALIDATE);

Answer (score 4):

The regex starts its life just as a string, so `left_identifier + text + right_identifier` and use that in `re.compile`

Or:

```
re.findall('{}(.*){}'.format(left_identifier, right_identifier), text)
```

works too.

You need to escape the strings in the variables if they contain regex metacharacter with [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) if you do not want the metacharacters interpreted as such:

```
>>> text = "<b*>Test</b>"
>>> left_identifier = "<b*>"
>>> right_identifier = "</b>"
>>> s='{}(.*?){}'.format(*map(re.escape, (left_identifier, right_identifier)))
>>> s
'\\<b\\*\\>(.*?)\\<\\/b\\>'
>>> re.findall(s, text)
['Test']
```

---

On a side note, [str.partition(var)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) is an alternate way to do this:

```
>>> text.partition(left_identifier)[2].partition(right_identifier)[0]
'Test'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you actually wanted a regex solution, but I really wonder if regex is the right tool here considering [we all have taken oath not to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/977038). When parsing html strings, I will always recommend to fall back to [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
>>> import bs4
>>> bs4.BeautifulSoup('<b*>Text</b>').text
u'Text'
```