# Regex to capture string until another string is encountered

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I want to match **string1** and anything that appears in the following lines:

```
['string1','string2','string3']
['string1' , 'string2' , 'string3']
['string1.domain.com' , 'string2.domain.com' , 'string3.domain.com']
['string1.domain.com:8080' , 'string2.domain.com:8080' , 'string3.domain.com:8080']
```

Until it encounters the following:

```
string2
```

So with the right regex in the above 4 cases the results in bold would be matched:

['**string1',**'string2','string3']

[**'string1' ,** 'string2' , 'string3']

['**string1.domain.com' ,** 'string2.domain.com' , 'string3.domain.com']

['**string1.domain.com:8080' ,** 'string2.domain.com:8080' , 'string3.domain.com:8080']

---

I tried using the following thread to solve my issue with https://regex101.com/

The regex I tried is from [Question 8020848](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020848/and-or-operator-in-regular-expression), but was not successful with matching the string correctly:

```
((^|\.lpdomain\.com:8080' , ')(string1))+$
```

But I was not successful in only matching the part I wanted to in this text:

```
['string1.domain.com:8080' , 'string2.domain.com:8080' , 'string3.domain.com:8080']
```

The following is what I received using the regex that you suggested

```
@@ -108,7 +108,7 @@ node stringA, stringB, stringC,stringD inherits default {
   'ssl_certificate_file' => 'test.domain.net_sha2_n.crt',
   'ssl_certificate_key_file'=> 'test.domain.net_sha2.key' }
 },
-    service_upstream_members         => ['string1.domain.com:8080', 'string2.domain.com:8080', 'string3.domain.com:8080', 'string4.domain.com:8080', 'string5.domain.com:8080'],
+    service_upstream_members         => [ 'string2.domain.com:8080', 'string3.domain.com:8080', 'string4.domain.com:8080', 'string5.domain.com:8080'],
 service2_upstream_members      => ['string9:8080','string10:8080'],
 service3_upstream_members  => ['string11.domain.com:8080','string12.domain.com:8080','string13.domain.com:8080'],
 service_name                      => 'test_web_nginx_z1',
```

As you can see, there is a preceding space that for some reason wasn't removed, even regex101.com demonstrates that all whitespaces are captured in the regex using

```
'string1[^']*'\s*,\s*
```

This is what I'm currently using (where server is a variable already defined in the script)

```
sed -i '' "s/'${server}[^']*'\s*,\s*//"
```

Comment: What about a [`'string1[^']*'`](https://regex101.com/r/eh9Rt8/1)?

Comment: Good, but won't include spaces. There are several combinations that could be: ','string2 OR ' , 'string2 OR ', 'string2 need it to include everything up until the ' immediately before string2

Comment: You mean you need spaces + comma + spaces, too? [`'string1[^']*'\s*,\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/eh9Rt8/3)?

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me.

Comment: I posted as the answer with explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I noticed some unexpected result when actually applying this regex with the sed [ tested using gnu-sed: stable 4.2.2 (bottled) ] It seems that my response is too long for this comment so I have posted more info as an answer (hope that is ok)

Comment: In sed, I'd rather use `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s`. Also, make sure the pattern is defined in a double quoted string literal. Note that regex101.com does not support POSIX regex syntax used in sed, you cannot say that if a regex at regex101 matches the string you provided, it should work in sed. It is not so.

Comment: BTW, [it works with the data you provided](https://ideone.com/MRpeSp).

Comment: I wonder if the sed on OSX is different from the linux version. The output i pasted is the result of git show HEAD with reflects the diff changes after running the sed command. Not sure why there is an extra space before the " ' ".

Comment: Try replacing both `\s` with `[[:space:]]`. Not sure it will help, I am no expert in Mac OSX, but yes, there is a difference as far as I know.

Comment: That did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a string starting with `'` then having `string1`, then any chars other than `'`, 0 or more occurrences, and then optional number of whitespaces, a comma and again 0+ whitespaces, you may use

```
'string1[^']*'\s*,\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eh9Rt8/3).

Breakdown:

- `'string1` - a literal char sequence `'string1`
- `[^']*` - zero or more (`*`) characters other than `'` (due to the negated character class `[^...]`)
- `'`  - an apostrophe
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

This should match what you ask (according to your **bold** highlights) allowing for an unknown amount of spaces, etc.

`(?:…)` is a *non-capturing* group.
`…+?` is a *non-greedy* match (as few as possible of *x*)

<del>`(string1.+?)(?:'string2)`</del>

`(string1.+?)'string2`

See example: https://regex101.com/r/lFPSEM/3

Comment: The `(?:'string2)` should not be inside a non-capturing group, there is only 1 branch inside the grouping construct here, and it is redundant.

Comment: You are right if you assume a consistent sequence of spaces, commas and single quotes is used. But your example would break as soon as that sequence is missing. I believe my approach reflects the OP's thinking of "from _this_ until _that_" more closely.

Comment: If it is that, I'd close the question as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736074/regex-matching-between-two-strings-in-python, and the right pattern is `('string1.+?)'string2`

Comment: Yup. A redundant non-capturing group :)

Comment: The [`(string1.+?)'string2`](https://regex101.com/r/lFPSEM/5) will capture `"string1', 'string0.sssss', "` in `['string1', 'string0.sssss', 'string2','string3']` and I doubt it is what is required judging by the provided input.

Comment: "[…] Until it encounters the following `string2`". As long the OP doesn't clarify further, I would refrain from assuming that is the case. Further, the input suspiciously looks like something that would better be parsed by other means than a regex…