# Find the text between two string pattern

Tags: python, regex

i have a log text like this.

```
data = '''
================================================================================
Annotation file:
/b/cd-builder/sandboxes/sb_DEV_COMMON_BRANCH-_act-builder-4977/annofile-4977TB53661_cd-builder.xml 

Build ID: 27951 on Host bng-emake-5a.juniper.net, Cluster Manager: bng-ea-cm-02:8030
Start Time: Sun Jun 17 23:57:30 2018


Job ID: J00002adde8677420 , Exit Value 1
CWD: /b/cd-builder/sandboxes/sb_DEV_COMMON_BRANCH-_act-builder-4977/obj/bsd11/amd64/junos/usr.sbin/rpd/bgp/lib/proto
Node: bng-ea-agent-14a-3  Start: 2018-06-18 00:20:55.488609 (1405.488609)
                          End:   2018-06-18 00:20:56.653945 (1406.653945)

Command:

export BMAKELOCATION=/b/cd-builder/sandboxes/sb_DEV_COMMON_BRANCH-_act-builder-4977/src/build/mk/jnx.sym_check.mk:37; CURDIR=/b/cd-builder/sandboxes/sb_DEV_COMMON_BRANCH-_act-builder-4977/src/junos/usr.sbin/rpd/bgp/lib/proto  OBJDUMP=/volume/hab/Linux/Ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/llvm/3.7/current/bin/amd64-unknown-freebsd11.0-objdump  BSS_SYMS=bss_syms.clang.amd64,bsdx  TLS_SYMS=tls_syms.clang.amd64,bsdx  ACCEPT_CMD='mk --machine amd64,bsd11 -C junos/usr.sbin/rpd/bgp/lib/proto accept-syms'  /volume/hab/Linux/Ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/bsd-tools/current/bin/sh /b/cd-builder/sandboxes/sb_DEV_COMMON_BRANCH-_act-builder-4977/src/build/scripts/sym_check.sh librpd-proto-bgp.a

------------------------------ Output ------------------------------
ERROR: /b/cd-builder/sandboxes/sb_DEV_COMMON_BRANCH-_act-builder-4977/src/junos/usr.sbin/rpd/bgp/lib/proto/tls_syms.clang.amd64,bsdx: changed global or static TLS variables
261a262
> bgp_inetsrte_incolor_update._xinfo

If correct, use:

    mk --machine amd64,bsd11 -C junos/usr.sbin/rpd/bgp/lib/proto accept-syms

make[1]: *** [check-syms] Error 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Operations:

================================================================================
+ echo -e '\e[31m Displaying Production.log.errs\e[0m'
 Displaying Production.log.errs
+ echo 'End Meta Error logs'
End Meta Error logs
'''
```

from this log text, I need to extract the text between "------------------------------ Output ------------------------------" and  "--------------------------------------------------------------------" so the output will be like this.

```
output = '''
ERROR: /b/cd-builder/sandboxes/sb_DEV_COMMON_BRANCH-_act-builder-4977/src/junos/usr.sbin/rpd/bgp/lib/proto/tls_syms.clang.amd64,bsdx: changed global or static TLS variables
261a262
> bgp_inetsrte_incolor_update._xinfo

If correct, use:

    mk --machine amd64,bsd11 -C junos/usr.sbin/rpd/bgp/lib/proto accept-syms

make[1]: *** [check-syms] Error 1
'''
```

not sure why my below code is not working.

```
for result in re.findall(r'------------------------------ Output ------------------------------(.*?) '
                         '--------------------------------------------------------------------', data, re.S):
    output += result
```

Comment: are the `-` es always the same?

Comment: [Remove the space after `(.*?)`](https://regex101.com/r/DzpHUH/1). Besides, you do not have to repeat each `-` in the pattern, use `-{5,}` instead, I think [it will be enough](https://regex101.com/r/DzpHUH/2).

Comment: removing space will not work here.

Comment: It will, see the demo links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex matching between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736074/regex-matching-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help. Regex `Lookbehind & Lookahead`

**Demo:**

```
import re
for result in re.findall(r'(?<=------------------------------ Output ------------------------------)(.*?)(?=--------------------------------------------------------------------)', data, re.S):    
    print(result)
```

Comment: @omtripathi This regex is the same as your solution (see no space after `(.*?)` as I suggested), just use this same code with your pattern minus the space. You may as well remove the `?<=` and `?=` and use `r'------------------------------ Output ------------------------------(.*?)--------------------------------------------------------------------'`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to match regex to do that. you can use `find` instead:

```
start = "------------------------------ Output ------------------------------"
end = "--------------------------------------------------------------------"

extracted_text = data[data.find(start)+len(start):data.rfind(end)]
```

the output will be:

> ERROR:
>   /b/cd-builder/sandboxes/sb_DEV_COMMON_BRANCH-_act-builder-4977/src/junos/usr.sbin/rpd/bgp/lib/proto/tls_syms.clang.amd64,bsdx:
>   changed global or static TLS variables 261a262
>
> > bgp_inetsrte_incolor_update._xinfo
>
> If correct, use:
>
> ```
> mk --machine amd64,bsd11 -C junos/usr.sbin/rpd/bgp/lib/proto accept-syms
> ```
>
> make[1]: *** [check-syms] Error 1

Comment: Thanks @AndreyF its working but i want to do it using regex.

Comment: So use @Rakesh answer

Answer (score 1):

regex is overkilling it. Your start / stop is unique thus the following would work:

```
start = "------------------------------ Output ------------------------------"
stop = "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
output = log.split(start)[1].split(stop)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output = ""
for result in re.findall(r'------------------------------ Output ------------------------------(.*?)'
                     '--------------------------------------------------------------------', data, re.S):
output += result

print output
```

The regex was not matching anything because of the space after `(.*?)`.

Answer (score -1):

And what about it?

```
reg=re.compile(r"-{10,} Output -{10,}(.*?)-{10,}",re.S)
rslt=reg.findall(data)
```