# How to get a value of a text block in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long string, that contains

```
Current: 98%
```

exactly one time. The percentage can be everything between 0 and 100.

E.g.:

```
This is a multi-line
output and the battery level is
Current: 100%
Thank you.
```

How can I just get the value between `Current:`  and `%`?

Comment: Hi. This is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736074/regex-matching-between-two-strings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex matching between two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736074/regex-matching-between-two-strings)

Comment: For sure the regex is a better solution, but if the pattern is that much simple, you can simply use `"""This is a multi-line
output and the battery level is
Current: 100%
""".split(": ")[1].split("%")[0]`, and there is no need to import a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regular expression for this exercise is overkill. Instead, find the position of the percent sign, trim the string at that position, split it, and take the last element:

```
text[:text.index('%')].split()[-1]
# '100'
```

I assume that there is only one `%` in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an approach such as the one below, using regular expressions.

```
import re
test = """
This is a multi-line
output and the battery level is
Current: 100%
Thank you.
"""
print(re.search(r'Current: (.*?)%', test).group(1))
```

**EDIT**:
If you need an integer out, you can just wrap the final value with `int()`:

```
result = int(re.search(r'Current: (.*?)%', test).group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex groups to pull out the percentage. This will match a numerical value between `Current:`  (with a space) and the `%` symbol.

```py
import re

text = """This is a multi-line
output and the battery level is
Current: 100%
Thank you."""

pattern = re.compile(r"Current: ([0-9]+)%")

result = re.search(pattern, text)
print(result.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the filter function on a string if you dont like re

```
int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, long_string)))
```

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'digit'

Comment: you are right, it is isdigit, as the default python shell points out: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'digit'. Did you mean: 'isdigit'?  Thank you