# HTML nested comments

Tags: html, comments

Assuming some HTML like this...

```
<section>
  <h1>Some stuff</h1>
  <!-- That was some stuff... -->
</section>
```

I add comment tags around the HTML I want to comment out. I want to comment out everything, but the comment is closed by existing comment.

```
<!--
<section>
  <h1>Some stuff</h1>
  <!-- That was some stuff... -->
</section>
-->
```

What is the best way to handle this scenario without losing all my inline comments.

Comment: Why do you comment everything ? This looks like a source management problem.

Comment: Seconding the Why?; possible duplicate of [Are nested HTML comments possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442786/are-nested-html-comments-possible)

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442786/are-nested-html-comments-possible).

Comment: @dystroy It's common during development to want to temporarily comment out a section. If that section happens to contain comments, you'll want them intact so you can revert by uncommenting the section. The fact that this isn't possible in XML is a language problem, not a user problem. Maxime's solution might help with HTML, but it won't work for header blocks / XML in general.

Answer (score 17):

A HTML comment start with a `<!--` and ends at the first `-->` encountered. There's no way to change this behavior. If you want to hide a large section with may contains comments **during the development**, you can wrap in a `<div style="display:none"></div>`. But don't do that in production, it's bad.

Comment: Why is it bad in production?

Comment: Because it can be qualified as "dead code": something that is useless, takes place, make the code less readable... You shouldn't have any code in comments in production because even if *"it could be useful some day"*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code

Comment: Thanks - just checking if there was some special badness about this particular way of creating dead code!

Comment: See the [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19790462/3944285)

Answer (score 17):

To comment block with nested comments:
sub inner (block) comments from "--"  to "~~"

```
<!-- *********************************************************************
     * IMPORTANT: to uncomment section
     *            sub inner comments "~~" -> "--" & remove this comment
     *********************************************************************
<head>
   <title>my doc's title</title> <~~! my doc's title ~~>
   <link rel=stylesheet href="mydoc.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body> 
<~~! my doc's important html stuff ~~>
...
...
...
</body>

*********************************************************************
* IMPORTANT: to uncomment section
*            sub inner comments "~~" -> "--" & remove this comment
*********************************************************************
-->
```

thus, outer most comment ignores all "invalid" inner (block) comments

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to block that.
You need to be careful what you are commenting out or not.

See : http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4

What you can try is to use PHP to comment out HTML code...
Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Look for shortcuts in your editor to do nested comments in html.

In VSCode I use this extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=philsinatra.nested-comments

This can with one keypress (un)comment a block of code and do a substitution of `<!-- inner-comment -->` to `<!~~ inner-comment ~~>` (just like guido's answer suggests), making commenting and uncommenting blocks just as easy as it is in other languages.

It also works for css /* comments */

There are probably similar extensions for other editors.

Comment: great suggestion. Don't know why it didn't occur to me to search for extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot comment it out without removing inner comments because HTML will consider the code as

```
<!--
<section>
----
----            //All this code comes under commented
----
some stuff... -->
```

It will consider only the beginning comment tag before `<section>` and end comment tag after "some stuff ...". So HTML will not treat the one comment tag after `<h1>` which is already under commented.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
<!--[if False]>
Lots of html including <!-- comments -->
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: False. If you add a label infront of last line in will show the text indicating that the closing tag of nested comment indeed closes the outer one